# Tika Server not reading embedded images in PDFs

Tags: openshift, tesseract, apache-tika, rhel7, tika-server

Hi Tika Server is setup with tesseract but still it is not reading embedded images in PDFs. Tried using the two headers available, but not help.

This is happening for PDF files only. While, OCR works for other file types/images.

Using customized docker container here. Oddly, the same container deployed in another machine works.
Is there any possibility of lower level issue?

**Update:**
After comparing logs, it seems OCP is lowercasing the custom HTTP headers like X-Tika..., Postman-Token to x-tika..., postman-token etc. Can anyone help me on what could be the possible issue?

Comment: One of the points of Docker containers is that they come batteries-included, and run the same everywhere.... Are you sure you're running the same containers on both machines, with the same environment variables passed in?

Comment: Yes. Though one is running on Kubernetes, and one in OCP. And no extra environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that OCP lowercasing the custom headers are reason for the issue.
TikaServer 1.25 does not support case insensitive X-Tika headers.

I have fixed it in Tika Server 1.26.
Ref: https://tika.apache.org/1.26/index.html
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3320

Answer (score -1):

Check the https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/parser/pdf/PDFParserConfig.html

```
pdfParserConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true);
pdfParserConfig.setOcrStrategy(PDFParserConfig.OCR_STRATEGY.OCR_ONLY);`
```

The pdf scanned document is converted to the image and then send to the tesseract

Comment: This answer doesn't directly respond to the tika-server point, and it conflates the two strategies: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=109454066#PDFParser(ApachePDFBox)-OCR